# Error when installing dlib on Python 3.5 using Windows 10

Tags: python, visual-studio, cmake, dlib

EDIT: Looks like I have to install Visual Studio 2015...Can I install dlib without VS 2015? I already have older versions pre-installed with Windows.

I am using Python 3.5, trying to install dlib on PyCharm in the terminal and this is what I am getting, and every search on these errors I do... I find stuff on Visual Studio which I don't have the GUI + I don't have vcvarsall.bat in the VC folder of any of the Visual Studio versions (8, 11, 12, 14). ***I have searched a good amount before posting this question on the Web.***
Do I need to download Visual Studio latest version to get vcvarsall.bat ?

This is CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION ${CMAKE_VERSION})
project(IntelFortranImplicit Fortran)
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT output.cmake
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${IntelFortranImplicit_SOURCE_DIR}/detect.cmake
  )
add_library(FortranLib hello.f output.cmake)
```

This is the error when I do: pip install dlib

```
  Collecting dlib
      Using cached dlib-19.6.1.tar.gz
    Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
      Running setup.py bdist_wheel for dlib ... error
      Complete output from command C:\Users\tiger\Anaconda3\envs\TensorFlowExample\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\tiger\\AppDat
    a\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-gjtgkl6a\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code
    , __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\tiger\AppData\Local\Temp\tmprc21rnv_pip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      error: Cannot find cmake, ensure it is installed and in the path.
      You can install cmake using the instructions at https://cmake.org/install/
      You can also specify its path with --cmake parameter.

      ----------------------------------------
      Failed building wheel for dlib
      Running setup.py clean for dlib
    Failed to build dlib
    Installing collected packages: dlib
      Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
        Complete output from command C:\Users\tiger\Anaconda3\envs\TensorFlowExample\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\tiger\\AppD
    ata\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-gjtgkl6a\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(co
    de, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\tiger\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-dk1naa28-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
    :
        running install
        running build
        error: Cannot find cmake, ensure it is installed and in the path.
        You can install cmake using the instructions at https://cmake.org/install/
        You can also specify its path with --cmake parameter.

        ----------------------------------------
    Command "C:\Users\tiger\Anaconda3\envs\TensorFlowExample\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\tiger\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-bu
    ild-gjtgkl6a\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))"
    install --record C:\Users\tiger\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-dk1naa28-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code
     1 in C:\Users\tiger\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-gjtgkl6a\dlib\
```

Comment: Are you using Anaconda? If so, you should install `dlib` with the `conda` package manager. Otherwise, yes, you need Visual Studio 2015 (or at least it's C++ build tools).

Comment: I am using `PyCharm` but I have `Anaconda environment variable`, `conda `package manager? I'll have to find that... please comment if u know how to open `conda package manager`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution found here:** [Using Anaconda installing manager..!](http://www.codesofinterest.com/2016/10/installing-dlib-on-anaconda-python-on.html)
Running the following in PyCharm Terminal: `conda install -c conda-forge dlib=19.4`
I was able to use dlib! :)

***Huge thanks to birryree in the comments for letting me know!***

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Anaconda Prompt in Administrative mode.
2. conda update conda 3. conda update anaconda
3. conda create -n dlib_env python=3.7
4. conda activate dlib_env
5. conda install -c conda-forge dlib
6. python
   7.1 >>> import dlib 7.2 >>> dlib.**version**

[Source](https://medium.com/@aaditya.chhabra/install-dlib-python-api-for-windows-pc-97fe35e01cd)